# Delete oldest file in directory iOS

Tags: ios

For some reason this method that I have written doesn't get rid of the oldest file in a directory even though everything seems fine from a logic point of view. Is there something subtle I am missing?

```
+(void)removeOldestFileFromDir:(NSURL *)dir forFileManager:(NSFileManager *)fm{
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *contents = [fm contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:[dir path] error:&error];
NSArray *jpgFiles = [contents filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self ENDSWITH '.jpg'"]];

NSDate *oldest = [NSDate date];
NSString *oldestFileName = nil;
for (NSString *f in jpgFiles) {
    NSString *photoPath = [[dir path] stringByAppendingPathComponent:f];

    NSDate *created = [[fm attributesOfItemAtPath:photoPath error:&error] objectForKey:@"NSFileCreationDate"];

    if([created compare:oldest] == NSOrderedAscending){
        oldestFileName = [NSString stringWithString:photoPath];
    }
}
[fm removeItemAtPath:oldestFileName error:&error];

}
```

I've checked the error and it's alway (null) and the file that gets deleting is seemingly random - sometimes it's the newest, sometimes it's another one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forget to set oldest variable inside of your if.

It should be like that:

```
 if([created compare:oldest] == NSOrderedAscending){
        oldestFileName = [NSString stringWithString:photoPath];
        oldest = created; // !!! This is what is missing
   }
```

Comment: THANKS! Probably the dumbest mistake I could have made but glad it's nothing more complicated, I was beginning to think iPhone programming was a thing for Einstens only.

Comment: @SimonBarker: Happened to all of us :)