# Delete oldest file from Documents folder in IOS

Tags: ios, file-management

I would like to know if there is any way to delete files in Documents folder in iOS via Date or something like the oldest file present in the Documents folder. My app downloads music files from the server and then stores it in the Documents folder. My client wants it that if the device space is below 1000 mb, the app would automatically delete oldest audio files in the Documets folder until it reaches 1.2k mb device space.

Is this possible experts? Great to hear from you soon. Thanks.

Comment: First get the size of the folder http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188469/calculate-the-size-of-a-folder

Comment: then http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15747777/delete-oldest-file-in-directory-ios

Comment: keep track of the folder size